# Splitting dates in 6months interval

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to split two dates into 6 months interval in Python. For example:

```
start_date = 2018-09-23
end_date = 2020-07-13
```

What i want as output in something like:

```
[2018-09-23, 2018-12-31] , [2019-01-01, 2019-06-30], [2019-07-01,2019-12-31], [2020-01-01, 2020-06-30], [2020-07-01, 2020-07-13]
```

Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: please share your attempt, also how is your output 6 month intervals?

Comment: Even the _two lines_ for start and end dates wouldn't be valid Python. Yes, we can help you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). **"Implement this feature for me"** is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_.

Comment: What are you using this for? I would imagine it would be more useful to return the month interval output as
`[2018-09-23, 2018-12-31, 2019-06-30]`.
This way I can get any 6 interval month date. Unless you specifically require then grouped in %0 month to %6 month iterations for different date ranges.

Comment: Sorry, you are right but i have no code on this topic. The solution provided below is helpful for my project. Thanks also to you for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.date_range()` returns the range of equally spaced time points.

```
start_date = '2018-09-23'
end_date = '2020-07-13'

pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='6M')
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-30', '2019-03-31', '2019-09-30', '2020-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6M')
```

Setting `freq = '6M'` creates equally spaced date time points, starting at the end of `start_date` month. We need to then shift all the dates back by the distance from our `start_date` to the end of the month, to ensure that our date time points begin with `start_date`

```
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='6M', closed='left')
dates = dates - pd.offsets.Day((dates[0] - pd.to_datetime(start_date)).days)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-23', '2019-03-24', '2019-09-23', '2020-03-24'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

We could now loop through our dates list, and create our date range list.

```
[[dates[i], dates[i+1]-pd.offsets.Day(1)] for i in range(len(dates)-1)]
```

Output:

```
[[Timestamp('2018-09-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-23 00:00:00')],[Timestamp('2019-03-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-09-22 00:00:00')],[Timestamp('2019-09-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-03-23 00:00:00')]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i think this solution is the best for my work.